# How can I indicate the path of a package in a String in Java?

Tags: java, file, package

```
new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Adam\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\TicTacToe_3.0 beta\\src\\resources\\System Shock 2 soundtrack Med Sci 1.mp3");

BufferedImage bf = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Adam\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\TicTacToe_3.0 beta\\src\\images\\black-squareMod.jpg"));
```

The two lines of code above are taking some kind of resource from the given paths. I would like to change them so that they will reference to a package within the same Netbeans project, which contains the same resources.

For example, the

> FileInputStream();

... is getting an audio file.

The

> BufferedImage bf = ImageIO.read(new File());

... is getting a .jpg image.

These two files are in a package called 'resources' in the same Netbeans project. How do I change the specified paths so that they go directly to those packages, instead of going through my hard disk?

Thanks.

Comment: the Class.getResource() and Class.getResourceAsStream() methods are relative to the class location. They are intended for this purpose.

Comment: This is what I thought. I implemented it, but got an exception stating that getResource() was returning null. I ensured that the source path was correct and listed in the project class path.

Comment: You don't need to use backslashes in Java filenames. Use `/`.

Comment: @EJP Yes, that is correct. Using the double backslashes actually caused exceptions when I tried to run my code.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution:

```
new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Adam\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\TicTacToe_3.0 beta\\src\\resources\\System Shock 2 soundtrack Med Sci 1.mp3");
```

Has been changed to

```
ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("resources/System Shock 2 soundtrack Med Sci 1.mp3");
```

That takes care of the audio.

As for the BufferedImage object:

```
BufferedImage bf = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Adam\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\TicTacToe_3.0 beta\\src\\images\\black-squareMod.jpg"));
```

Was changed to

```
BufferedImage bf = ImageIO.read(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("images/black-squareMod.jpg"));
```

Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

the Class.getResource() and Class.getResourceAsStream() methods are relative to the class location. They are intended for this purpose.

from javadoc

```
Finds a resource with a given name. The rules for searching resources associated
with a given class are implemented by the defining class loader of the class. This 
method delegates to this object's class loader. If this object was loaded by the 
bootstrap class  loader, the method delegates to ClassLoader.getSystemResource(java.lang.String).

Before delegation, an absolute resource name is constructed from the given resource
name using this algorithm:

If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of the resource is 
the portion of the name following the '/'.

Otherwise, the absolute name is of the following form:
modified_package_name/name Where the modified_package_name is the package name of 
this object with '/' substituted for '.' ('\u002e').
```

A sample program this will acquire the url to file in src/resources/test.properties if it exists.

```
public class TestGetResource {

    public TestGetResource(){
        Object resource = this.getClass().getResource("/test.properties");
        System.out.println(resource);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new TestGetResource();
    }
}
```

to debug try this

```
Object resource = this.getClass().getResource("/");
```

This should return the binary path for the project. Have a look in there NetBeans should
copy all the resources in there when it makes the project if it doesn't then you will get
the null.

your directory structure should be

`src/main/java`
`src/main/resources`

Comment: I tried your debugging code, by making an Object object and using the getResource() method, passing a URL of "/". Netbeans promptly printed out the path of my project at .../build/class.

I just can't seem to make this work with the BufferedImage object, or the FileInput stream... either the constructor disagrees, or the getResource() method returns null.

Comment: @Adam Ali NetBeans should be moving the resources into that directory. on build. If it isn't then getResource will not find it.

Comment: You're right, the files have been moved - now that I checked that folder. So what difference does this make? I still can't seem to use getResource() with FileInputStream or BufferedImage().

How do I use it with those classes?